# Prove that $\beta$ is a root of a $n$ degree polynomial of K [x] with leading coefficient $1$.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Prove that $\beta$ is a root of a $n$ degree polynomial of K [x] with leading coefficient $1$. Here $K$ is UFD,
$Q$ is its field of fractions,
$Q(\beta)$ is algebraic extension of $n>1$ degree of the field of fractions, obtained by adjoining integral over $K$ element $\beta$.

Comment: Please edit the question into the body; it should be there, not just in the title.

Comment: Never mind; I'll do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a consequence of [Gauss' Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29).

---

That is, consider the monic polynomial $f$ of minimal degree in $K[x]$ which has $\beta$ as a root. This is clearly irreducible in $K[x]$, and thus, by Gauss' Lemma, also in $Q[x]$. So $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $Q$, and thus $n = \lvert Q(\beta) : Q \rvert = \operatorname{degree(f)}$.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, why it's a consequence.
Gauss' Lemma sais that the product of two primitive polynomials is primitive and if a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients is irreducible over the integers, then it is also irreducible if it is considered as a polynomial over the rationals.

Comment: If you don't understand, why have you accepted?

Comment: @UncleSam, I have added an explanation.